# DFA Reporting API: how to get a list of reports files

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-reporting-trafficking-api

According to the official documentation [DCM/DFA Reporting and Trafficking API](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/reporting/v2.3/reports/files/list) this the way to get a list of reports files in json format:

```
   $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/dfareporting/v2.3/userprofiles/" . $this->profile_id . "/reports/" . $this->report_id . "/files?key=" . $this->developer_key;

   $opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => "GET",
            'header' => "content-encoding:  gzip,
                        content-length:  863,
                        content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    var_dump($response);
```

However, `$response` returns me false. I have played with it in API explorer, and it works fine there. Any thoughts?

Comment: According to the api "The DCM/DFA Reporting and Trafficking API v1.x, v2.0, and v2.1 are deprecated and will be sunset on February 29th, 2016. All users must migrate to a newer API version by this date."

Comment: @RamRaider if you pay attention to the url, it says v2.3

Comment: ok - just thought I'd mention it ~ should have read it better to begin with